# IdentityServer4 with Hybrid WinForms OidcClient2 - auth flow opens browser after login

Tags: identityserver4

I've succesfully used WinForms sample from IdentityModel.OidcClient v2 to invoke an API secured with IdentityServer4.

IS is configured with two external providers, Google and ADFS; implementation is based on IS4 quickstarts.

Authentication works fine, WinForms application receives a valid refresh token and is able to invoke a secured API, but I'm confused by the external login callback behavior.

After succesful login, the embedded browser closes and default browser is opened (Chrome in my laptop), and reaches the ExternalLoginCallback.

Then the WinForms gets the refresh token, but then chrome tab stays open and is redirected to the IS login page.

How can I prevent showing / close chrome browser window?
Do I have to tweak the ExternalLogin action?

**Update**

Adding client code and lib/server info:

WinForm client with 
IdentityModel v 3.0.0 
IdentityModel.OidcClient 2.4.0
asp.net mvc server with 
IdentityServer4 version 2.1.1 
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework 2.1.1

Following WinForm client code:

```
public partial class SampleForm : Form
{
    private OidcClient _oidcClient;
    private HttpClient _apiClient;

    public SampleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var options = new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            ClientId = "native.hybrid",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            Scope = "openid email offline_access myscope myapi1 myapi2",

            RedirectUri = "http://localhost/winforms.client",

            ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.FormPost,
            Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.Hybrid,

            Browser = new WinFormsEmbeddedBrowser()
        };

        _oidcClient = new OidcClient(options);
    }

    private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AccessTokenDisplay.Clear();
        OtherDataDisplay.Clear();

        var result = await _oidcClient.LoginAsync(new LoginRequest());

        if (result.IsError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, result.Error, "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            AccessTokenDisplay.Text = result.AccessToken;

            var sb = new StringBuilder(128);
            foreach (var claim in result.User.Claims)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"{claim.Type}: {claim.Value}");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result.RefreshToken))
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"refresh token: {result.RefreshToken}");
            }

            OtherDataDisplay.Text = sb.ToString();

            _apiClient = new HttpClient(result.RefreshTokenHandler);
            _apiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5003/");
        }
    }

    private async void LogoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //await _oidcClient.LogoutAsync(trySilent: Silent.Checked);
        //AccessTokenDisplay.Clear();
        //OtherDataDisplay.Clear();
    }

    private async void CallApiButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_apiClient == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var result = await _apiClient.GetAsync("identity");
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            OtherDataDisplay.Text = JArray.Parse(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            OtherDataDisplay.Text = result.ReasonPhrase;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

ExternalLoginCallback code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
    {
        // read external identity from the temporary cookie
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
        if (result?.Succeeded != true)
        {
            _logger.LogError(result.Failure, "External athentication error.");
            throw new Exception("External authentication error");
        }

        // retrieve claims of the external user
        var externalUser = result.Principal;
        var claims = externalUser.Claims.ToList();

        ....LOOKING FOR THE USER (OMITTED FOR BREVITY)....

        var additionalClaims = new List<Claim>();

        // if the external system sent a session id claim, copy it over
        // so we can use it for single sign-out
        var sid = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.SessionId);
        if (sid != null)
        {
            additionalClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.SessionId, sid.Value));
        }

        // if the external provider issued an id_token, we'll keep it for signout
        AuthenticationProperties props = null;
        var id_token = result.Properties.GetTokenValue("id_token");
        if (id_token != null)
        {
            props = new AuthenticationProperties();
            props.StoreTokens(new[] { new AuthenticationToken { Name = "id_token", Value = id_token } });
        }

        // issue authentication cookie for user
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, userId, user.Id.ToString(), user.Username));
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id.ToString(), user.Username, provider, props, additionalClaims.ToArray());
        _logger.LogInformation("User {user} logged in with external provider.", userId);

        // delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

        // validate return URL and redirect back to authorization endpoint or a local page
        var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"];
        if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl) || Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return Redirect("~/");
    }
```

Client configuration on IdentityServer, serialized:

```
{
"Enabled": true,
"ClientId": "native.hybrid",
"ProtocolType": "oidc",
"RequireClientSecret": true,
"ClientName": "Application",
"LogoUri": null,
"RequireConsent": false,
"AllowRememberConsent": true,
"AllowedGrantTypes": [
  "hybrid"
],
"RequirePkce": false,
"AllowPlainTextPkce": false,
"AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true,
"RedirectUris": [
  "http://localhost/winforms.client"
],
"FrontChannelLogoutUri": null,
"FrontChannelLogoutSessionRequired": true,
"BackChannelLogoutUri": null,
"BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired": true,
"AllowOfflineAccess": true,
"AllowedScopes": [
  "openid",
  "email",
  "profile",
  "myscope",
  "offline_access",
  "myapi1",
  "myapi2"
],
"AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken": false,
"IdentityTokenLifetime": 300,
"AccessTokenLifetime": 3600,
"AuthorizationCodeLifetime": 300,
"AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime": 2592000,
"SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime": 1296000,
"ConsentLifetime": null,
"RefreshTokenUsage": 1,
"UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh": false,
"RefreshTokenExpiration": 1,
"AccessTokenType": 0,
"EnableLocalLogin": true,
"IdentityProviderRestrictions": [
  "Google",
  "WsFederation"
],
"IncludeJwtId": false,
"Claims": [],
"AlwaysSendClientClaims": false,
"ClientClaimsPrefix": "client_",
"PairWiseSubjectSalt": null,
"Properties": {}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a scenario with local authentication? Does it have the same issue? Do you have some browser specific settings for opening new domain in a new window?

Comment: This seems more a WebBrowser issue. Perhaps this link may help you: https://dotnetninja.wordpress.com/2008/02/26/prevent-opening-new-window-from-webbrowser-control/

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 I added local authentication alongside external providers and it works fine. I have default chrome browser settings.

Comment: @MarcoGallinari - In the client configuration of your WinForms client, what urls have you configured?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I tried adding NewVindow and NewWindow3 events but they never get fired.

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 Authority and RedirectUri

Comment: Have you modified `WinFormsEmbeddedBrowser` or `ExtendedWebBrowser`?

Comment: don't know if this could proof anyting, but debugging the application I can see that Chrome browser opens after the WinForm WebBrowser is hidden and the WebView returns the post response to OidcClient

Comment: No, just tried to add NewWindow3 event to check if I could catch something

Comment: Give some code. Specifically - around the login call to IDS. Also - which versions of `IdentityModel` and `IdentityModel.OidcClient` are you using

Comment: code added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could answer very long but in the end the quickstart code you used was the root cause of this issue.
To be exact it's this code that's causing the issue:

```
// validate return URL and redirect back to authorization endpoint or a local page
var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"];
if (_interaction.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl) || Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}

return Redirect("~/");
```

it should become this instead:

```
// retrieve return URL
var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";

// check if external login is in the context of an OIDC request
var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
if (context != null)
{
    if (await _clientStore.IsPkceClientAsync(context.ClientId))
    {
        // if the client is PKCE then we assume it's native, so this change in how to
        // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
        return View("Redirect", new RedirectViewModel { RedirectUrl = returnUrl });
    }
}

return Redirect(returnUrl);
```

This would also mean that you need an extension class method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the client is configured to use PKCE.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="store">The store.</param>
    /// <param name="clientId">The client identifier.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<bool> IsPkceClientAsync(this IClientStore store, string clientId)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientId))
        {
            var client = await store.FindEnabledClientByIdAsync(clientId);
            return client?.RequirePkce == true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The missing viewmodel:

```
public class RedirectViewModel
{
    public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }
}
```

This missing javascript file with this content located in wwwroot/js/signin-redirect.js

```
window.location.href = document.querySelector("meta[http-equiv=refresh]").getAttribute("data-url");
```

and as last a new razor page Redirect.cshtml located in the Views/Shared

```
@model RedirectViewModel

<h1>You are now being returned to the application.</h1>
<p>Once complete, you may close this tab</p>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=@Model.RedirectUrl" data-url="@Model.RedirectUrl">
<script src="~/js/signin-redirect.js"></script>
```

This should do the trick or you can update your quickstart code. But it's not an issue in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `ResponseMode` is the thing that bothers you. Why don't you remove it from the OIDC client settings. The flow can also go for now (just make sure it is properly configured on IDS side). Also - monitor the logs of Identity Server, for any errors.

Comment: I have two ResponseModes available: FormPost (which is default value when not set) and Redirect; Redirect is not working, looking at the code I think the WebView is designed for FormPost response. Found no errors in IS logs.
Maybe the flow works but something is missing on the IS side; adding IS configuration and ExternalLoginCallback.

Comment: I saw you have `WsFederation` authentication. Is it behaving the same way? It's very strange, because I have the exact same scenario (I just embed the `WebBrowser` in the form, but before it was opening) and no such problem, but I'm not using Google as external provider. I'm just wondering could it be. Can you debug the `ExternalLoginCallback` and see when exactly this happens? And is it opening another browser window or this happens in the one in which you login?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and what worked for me was to change the RedirectUri to a different value that does not start with http.

```
        var options = new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = "<path to ids>",
            ClientId = "<your client id>",
            Flow = OidcClientOptions.AuthenticationFlow.Hybrid,
            ClientSecret = "<your super secret phrase>",
            Scope = "<your scopes>",
            RedirectUri = "winformsclients://callback", // <-- HERE IS THE ANSWER
            Browser = new WinFormsWebView(),
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "winformsclients://callback", // <-- HERE IS THE ANSWER
        };

        var oidcClient = new OidcClient(options);
```

Important to the above solution would be that your Client configuration on your IdentityServer (in the database) need to be updated with this dummy uri.

The tables where this has to be configured are:

***ClientCorsOrigins**, **ClientRedirectUris** and **ClientPostLogoutRedirectUris***

you can also download a sample app from the link below and customize it.

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/WinFormsWebView

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to authenticate using Google. A possible workaround/fix is documented here:

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/issues/283